# Is it allowed to use $\geq$ and $>$ in this way?

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

Is this allowed? Is it valid to use $\geq$ and $>$ in this way. I am feeling a bit insecure because I do not have much mathematical experience.

I had that $|z-2| < 1$

$$|z| = |z-2 + 2| \geq ||z-2| + |2|| = ||z-2| + 2| \implies 2 - |z-2| $$ so $$|z| = |z-2 + 2| \geq 2 - |z-2| > 2 - 1 = 1$$ So $|z|>1$

I used that $-|z-2|> -1$.

Comment: Could you please explain the step $ | |z-2|+2 | \Rightarrow 2-|z-2|$

Comment: What about $z=\frac{1}{2}+0i$?

Comment: what you wrote is not correct. check with $z=\frac{3}{2}$.

Comment: @AbdallahHammam It has to be right because it is an exercise (I know how this sounds). Show that $1 < |z| < 3$ **if** $|z-2|<1$. Also $z = \frac{3}{2} > 1 $.

Comment: @HughEntwistle $2 - |z - 2|$ is a real number. If $|x| = 2$ I can conclude that $x = 2$ or $x = -2$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint for the first.

We have

$$|z-2|<1 \implies$$

$$-1<z-2<1 \implies$$

$-1<z-2$  and  $z-2<1 \implies$

$-1+2<z-2+2$  and

$z-2+2<1+2 \implies$

$1<z$  and  $z<3 \implies$

$$1<z<3$$.

Comment: Thank you. To be really strict you have not answered my question which was not so much about the problem _per se_ but to whether you can mix the usage of $\geq$ and $>$ as I did.